# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' i don't understand why

Tags: python

The code below gives me : unhashable type: 'list'

I  don't understand why because i'm not modifying the keys i'm only if some value is empty. Other thing that i don't understand is that why the code doesn't
give me  error immediately but after some iteration. For example the lines
if dct[elem] == [] doesn't give the error immediately after same iteration give
error. This line too dct[key].append(dct[elem]).
Please help me.

Thank you very much!

```
def compiti(dct,insi):
    for key,value in dct.items():   
        for elem in value:
            ls=[]
            ls+=elem
            if dct[elem] == []:
                break 
            else:
                    d = {k:v for k,v in dct.items() if k in insi}
        return d
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what `dct` and `insi` might look like?

Answer (score 1):

The error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` is due to the fact that, your code is trying to assign a list as a key to a dictionary. The list, being a mutable type cannot be used as a key to a dictionary. The list is not hashable because if you modify the list later on its hash will change, and the dictionary lookup would fail.

This is the reason `dct[key].append(dct[elem])` is also giving you the same error.

Comment: but here i'm not assigning if dct[elem] == []: i'm comparing if the value is empty!

Comment: Can you provide the sample value for `dct` used? The `elem` seems to be a list in this case.